# how do add content and properties to empty view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

My problem is that I need to add content to an empty view. More precisely I need to make my own view with some informations from my database. I need to know where to start from. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think these [step-by-step video tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc) will help you start.